# How can I filter through an array an return it instead of another one in this Svelte project?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am working on a small Svelte application, for learning purposes (Im new to Svelte).

The application displays a JSON of countries in a Bootstrap 4 table. There is also a text box that can be used to filter through the countries:

```
const apiURL = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json";

let countries = [];
let filteredCountries = [];
let stringToMatch = '';

onMount(async function() {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    countries = await response.json();
    filteredCountries = countries;
});

function filterList(){
  filteredCountries = countries;

  if(stringToMatch){
    filteredCountries = countries.filter(country => {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) || country.code.includes(stringToMatch.toUpperCase());
    });
  }
}
```

See a REPL with the entire code **[HERE](https://svelte.dev/repl/8ed025d425a043b4815cc29e91ed4bd9?version=3.26.0)**.

I am looking for a way to filter through the `countries` array and return *it* filtered, instead of using JavaScript's `filter()` method which requires storing the results in another variable.

In other words, I wish I would not need the `filteredCountries` variable.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: filter does create a new array BUT assigns that to whatever variable you specify.  Thus, myArray = myArray.filter(....) would simply replace the value of myArray.  If you need to keep the original array, then you assign the value to a new array:  let myFilteredArray = myArray.filter(...)

Comment: @ATD Doing `countries = countries.filter(country => {
    return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) || country.code.includes(stringToMatch.toUpperCase())});` does not get me the right result. I may have understood you wrong. How would you do the trick?

Comment: You've missed out a ; near the end: .....toUpperCase());});  otherwise, the codes are the same except for the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea would be to use an `getFilteredCountries()` function so you don't need this `filteredCountries` variable.

You can define it like that:

```js
function getFilteredCountries(countries, stringToMatch){
    if(stringToMatch){
        return countries.filter(country => {
            return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase()) || country.code.includes(stringToMatch.toUpperCase());
        });
    } else {
        return countries
    }
}
```

and consume it in your `#each`:

```html
{#each getFilteredCountries(countries, stringToMatch) as country}   
    <tr>
        <td>{country.name}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{country.code}</td>
    </tr>
{/each}
```

See a REPL with the entire code [HERE](https://svelte.dev/repl/ff5edc6c94c547ae968ba4719539af5c?version=3.26.0).

Comment: What if I need to loop the `countries` array in the HTML part?

Comment: Exactly the same way you have done before : `{#each countries as country}`.

Comment: I need to loop the `countries` array in the template, and replacing `{#each getFilteredCountries(countries, stringToMatch) as country}` with `{#each countries as country}` does not work. See **[HERE](https://svelte.dev/repl/e07e28ace32945838088b7fb41905319?version=3.26.0)**.

Comment: Yes because if you want the filtered countries, you need to use the `getFilteredCountries` function.